# Making a two-way bridge between two interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

I want to bridge a connection, I made a quick drawing of my setup: (eth0 isn't connected to anything). All of the computers are running CentOS 7.

[image: Network Diagram]

I wish to allow PC A to ping and send packets to PC B, and vice versa. Both of the PCs should also be able to ping / send packets to the server, however they should not be able to access the internet. I have tried solutions with iptables such as [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/453254/routing-between-two-networks-on-linux), but that only allowed PC A to ping the server, no interconnection.

Do you have any idea how I could set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy: do not specify default gateway/default route on PC's A and B. This should keep both A and B from reaching the Internet and each other. To allow A and B to communicate with each other, add static routes on each PC to reach the other's network. Add a static route on PC A to PC B's network, and add a static route on PC B to PC A's network.

Assume that PC A's network is 10.0.0.0/30 and PC B's network is 10.0.0.4/30. On PC A, run (as root) `route add -net 10.0.0.4/30 gw [ip_of_eth2]` and on PC B, run (also as root) `route add -net 10.0.0.0/30 gw [ip_of_eth3]`. Also, make sure that IP forwarding is enabled on the server (i.e. `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should be `1`).

This is of course routing, not bridging, but it is more suitable based on your topology and need.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't modify the routing information on my PCs because of an unrelated reason. Thank you for your answer though! I'll keep it here as future reference for people creating similar situations. I managed to find an old router lying around and just connected all three computers to it. That eliminated any need for bridging or routing.